# Disable WGET history tracking

Tags: terminal, environment-variables, wget

I am looking for a way to permanently remove the `.wget-hsts` in my home directory.

There is an optional tag that can be added per-wget request to not store history, however, that option needs to be added every time wget is used.

Is there some sort of environment variable or other configuration that will allow me to disable the writing to `.wget-hsts`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, the answer appears to be no. The workaround I placed in my `.bashrc`:

`alias wget="wget --hsts-file ~/dotfiles/config/wget/wget-hsts"`

This question was asked on the mailing list and [the respondent suggested](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-wget/2017-03/msg00051.html) modifying the command in the .wgetrc, but as of this answer there is no documented `hsts-file` command over at https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Wgetrc-Commands.html, and my attempts to try and set it there anyway were unsuccessful (received an error message).

Answer (score 10):

It appears that as of now, the .wgetrc option is working in Debian.
Option for ~/.wgetrc is simply.

```
hsts=0
```

Comment: This works, but for me it seems to disable the HSTS completely. I wonder if there is a solution to enable HSTS for the command session/run. Like if any site would try to redirect back to HTTP so HSTS would kick in.

Answer (score 3):

There is a specific option that supports this (at least for version >=1.21.3)

```bash
alias wget='wget --no-hsts'
```

Answer (score 2):

I had success dealing with this same file (on OS X 10.13.6) by creating a directory with the same name (".wget-hsts").  My experience is that some software is smart enough to handle 'protective' permissions issues in log files, but (so far) making a directory with the undesirable log/cfg file's name has always worked for me (based on my experience on Android & Mac systems).

Answer (score -1):

If you already know the command-line option to disable this feature, you can put this option in your $HOME/.wgetrc file. This file is explained in wget's manual page, which is also available online in https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html

Alternatively, I am guessing (but didn't try) that if you create the log file and make it unwritable, wget will silently ignore it.

Comment: the discussion at https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-wget/2017-03/msg00051.html has a similar discussion, but it appears that this option can be specified at the command-line and not in the `.wgetrc` file